# how to change the direction of CollapsingToolbarLayout's title?

Tags: java, android, right-to-left

I used Design Support Library in my project and want to change the direction of CollapsingToolbarLayout's title from ltr to rtl(as you can see below).how can I do that?

[image: CollapsingToolbarLayout's title is right to left]

I checked [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) but couldn't find anything usefull.
the layout for this design is not ready yet, but this is a similar xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Info"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Friends"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Related"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: Post Your XML Please.

Comment: you also could change the direction by forcing the view to RTL. `getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);` . but for api bellow 17 this wouldn't work

Comment: @hadi that code does not work in this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

at the end,I find that I can do this in both xml and java:
these attribute in xml code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
   app:collapsedTitleGravity="right"
   app:expandedTitleGravity="right"
```

or these codes in java

```
collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

can change the direction of title.

Comment: Note that it's advised to add the vertical gravity too: for collapsedTitleGravity add center_vertical , and for expandedTitleGravity add bottom

Comment: I don't understand why "start" value doesn't works. It should be on the right for right-left language and on left for others. But it is still on the left.

Comment: @ATom maybe you add  ' android:supportsRtl="true" ' in your manifest

Comment: @HamedGh I addedd android:supportsRtl="true" in menufest as well, but still its not working.

Answer (score 1):

I **remove** ExpandedTitleGravity and CollapsedTitleGravity **from xml** and i check direction of layout and **add programmatically** gravity to the collapsingToolbarLayout as bellow.

**Be sure that in your if condition you are getting direction properly, sometimes its not giving right direction.**

```
    if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection("your_view_here") == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR) {
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    } else {
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleGravity(Gravity.END | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    }
```